# Triggering a javascript event with inline parameters

Tags: javascript, html, forms, anchor, contextmenu

I have a form on my website which is submitted by clicking a link. I am trying to create a custom context menu so that a user can open the submitted form in a new tab, if desired. Because the pages are generated dynamically with cgi, the parameters of the functions are different each time. I would like to trigger the function with those parameters after adding the attribute `target="_blank"` to the form element.

I am able to access the parameters by using `document.getElementById("...").onclick` and then using regexes to extract them. But this seems overcomplicated. I feel there must be a way to say, in effect, "do what you would have done if someone had left-clicked this a element". Here is some simplified code:

```
<a id = "link" style = "cursor:pointer" onclick = "postform('1')">link</a>
<FORM id = "remote"><input id = "input" type = "hidden" name = "firstkey" value = ""></FORM>
```

I have the JS in a separate file, it basically says:

```
function postform(valueone) {
document.getElementById("input").value = valueone;
document.getElementById("remote").submit();
}
```

what I have now for opening in a new tab is:

```
function contextmenu() {
  var parameters =document.getElementById("newtab").onclick;
  //regexes go here
  postform(parameters);
 }
```

What I am asking is, is there a way in a line or two to replace what I am doing inside the contextmenu function which would fire the onclick event attached to the link with its parameters?

Comment: lookup `this` and then pass it in for a reference to what was clicked

Comment: I'm not sure how that would look - my question as far as I can tell is not how to reference the element but how to trigger the event attached to it - if I wrote `this.onclick` for example, I would be in the same position I described in the question.

Comment: so you want to trigger a click on a given element?

Comment: essentially, yes - whatever would get the "onclick" attached to that element to fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can programmatically fire a click event of a node using its click method.

So for an element of id 'newtab':

```
document.getElementById("newtab").click();
```

*Note:  wrap that in some error checking in case the node isnt found for some reason.